# yfinance "history" function not working in my python sessions, how can I debug this?

Tags: python, yfinance

I'm new to python, and im trying to run a few shareprice related projects.

However .history function never works for me.

```
import yfinance as yf

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
msft.info
hist = msft.history(period="max")
```

.info runs fine, however .history produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    hist = msft.history(period="max")
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 157, in history
    data = data.json()
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

does anyone know what might be causing this? or how to go about debugging it?

Comment: error means that it get empty JSON and it can't convert it to dict/list. As I know `yfinance` uses data from Yahoo and it may not send history data.  Or it may need different arguments to get data - for wrong arguments it may simply send nothing.

Comment: this code gives me error `HTTP Error 404: Not Found` - so page with history data may not exists any more, or it blocked for some time or for some countries.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version (0.1.62) will fix the problem. See [here](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/363).

Answer (score 3):

You should upgrade yfinance.  Run this on the command line:

```
pip install yfinance==0.1.62
```